# Uri Builder in android - '/' replaced by '%2F' and ":" is replaced by "%3A"

Tags: android, url, uri

I want to build the following URI -

```
https://10.112.88.182:8443/Vehicle/services/socialService/login
```

...

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.scheme(Constants.URL_SCHEME);
builder.authority(host);
builder.appendPath(service + "/" +method);
return builder.build().toString();
```

where

- `URL_SCHEME` - `https`
- `host` - `10.112.88.182:8443/Vehicle/services/`
- `service` - `socialService`
- `method` - `login`

When this code runs I get the following URI -

```
https://10.112.88.182%3A8443%2FVehicle%2Fservices%2F/socialService%2Flogin
```

`/` is replaced by `%2F` and `:` is replaced by `%3A`

Answer (score 40):

That's how `Uri.Builder` works. It encodes non-safe URL characters with special meaning to their `%xx` hex values.

To prevent encoding URI parts that are already properly encoded, use the `encoded` versions of builder functions:

```
builder.encodedAuthority(host);
builder.appendEncodedPath(service + "/" +method);
```

But since all your URL parts are already ready and don't need any further encoding, it's easier to just use a regular `StringBuilder` to concatenate the parts.

Comment: then how will I be able to add ':' after my IP (before port 8443) ?

Comment: If `host` is set to `10.112.88.182:8443`, then you could build your path so that it will be `Vehicle/services/socialService/login` which I believe can be done by `.appendPath(Vehicle/services)`, plus additional `.appendPath()` or `.appendEncodedPath()` as needed.

Comment: How would you add something with a comma as a query parameter? `appendQueryParameter("zipcode", "12346,US")` encoded the `,`.

Answer (score 10):

Like laalto said, this is how Uri.Builder works but if you want to get the uri in a regular url form, like in your case: `https://10.112.88.182:8443/Vehicle/services/socialService/login`
 you can do:

```
URL url = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(builder.build().toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  Because the original request is trying to return a string, the best answer is simply `return URLDecoder.decode(builder.build().toString(), "UTF-8");`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple, simply use `appendEncodedPath()`, it will not encode your string, it just appends it as it is.